# Are there benefits in migrating from LocalDb 2012 to LocalDb 2014?

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, localdb

We use EntityFramework with a localDb 2012 database in production because of its ease of installation on client computers and its good performance. So, we have no pressing need to change this.
Would there be any benefit from migrating to LocalDb 2014 notwithstanding?

Answer (score 1):

One I can think of would be the new cardinality estimator, which may improve performane of some queries